# CodeIgniter model where statements for specific result. Can't figure it out

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, where-clause, models

Project is in CI. I'm stuck on writing a where statement.

I have a table with many fields, but want to focus on filter by **'user_type'** and **'photos_count'**.

I have a feed that generates the proper users, but I want to add a where statement that if **'user_type'** is **'1'**, check to see if **'photos_count' is not '0'**. Basically if **'user_type'** is **'1'** and he his **'photos_count'** is **'0'**, don't return him in results. BUT, only if **'user_type'** is **'1'**, if **'user_type'** is **'2,3,4, etc'**. they can have 0 photos and still be returned in the results.

Best I could do would check if 'photos_count' != '0' for all user_types, not just user_type 1.

```
$this->db->where('user_type', 1)
$this->db->where('photos_count !=', 0)
```

I tried searching here, but just couldn't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: You just want check for 'user_type' is '1' with condition 'photos_count' != '0' or you also want to check if 'user_type' is greater then '1'?

Comment: @prashantthakre I want to return all user_types regardless of photos_count, except for user_type 1. If user_type 1 has 0 photos, don't return, else return everyone else.

Comment: Then in PHP, these above two lines you can put inside the if condition. Like if user_type is 1 only then your if block will exceute and in sql it will append where clause.lemme know if my understanding is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` in `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  t 
WHERE 
  CASE
    WHEN user_type = 1 
    THEN photos_count > 0 
    ELSE TRUE 
  END
```

### [`Fiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/022d76/1)

While writing active record query you can do so

```
$result=$this->db->select('*')
             ->from('t')
             ->where('CASE
                        WHEN user_type = 1 
                        THEN photos_count > 0 
                        ELSE TRUE 
                      END ',null,FALSE)
             ->get()
             ->result();
```